# Is my mdadm command correct, should I check something else before entering it?

Tags: raid, mdadm

**The question**: Would someone please confirm that I have investigated the correct factors and am about to use the correct `mdadm` command before I do something that might damage the data in my currently-inaccessible Raid 1 array?

**The details**: I lost the ability to access my Raid 1 in a lapse of concentration where I used `mkfs.exfat` on `/dev/md0p1` instead of on an SD card. Ubuntu 14.04 lives on a bootable partition of `sdc`, while `sda1` and `sdb1` comprised the multidisk array. The array also used to be mounted as my `home` directory, so without it, I can't log into Ubuntu as myself. I am booting off `sdc` and dropping to root to try to fix the problem from the terminal. (From here, though, I don't know how to mount the array... assuming I can fix it.)

I have read and reread the man pages for `mdadm` and have looked at the `mdadm --detail` for `/dev/md/0` and everything seems to be in order.

```
/dev/me/0:
Version : 1.2
               ...
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
               ...
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
               ...
           Name : crossroads:0  (local to host crossroads)
           UUID : [matches the one in mdadm.conf]
         Events : 1439
```

And the table at the bottom lists `active sync` for both drives.

Similarly, `mdadm --examine` for both the drives looks to be totally okay. I am not going to type it all out, but the checksums are correct, they both are listed as part of the same array UUID (the correct one from `mdadm.conf`), all the other details of each drive are identical except their Device UUIDs. Both show `Array State : AA`.

**Restating the question** I think I am ready to run `mdadm --assemble /dev/md/0 /dev/sd[ab]1`, but I am not 100% sure of the command, and I am positively terrified that I will do something that permanently wrecks the data on `sda` or `sdb`. Would someone please let me know if I'm missing anything?