# How do I recover my RAID 1 file system after formatting it?

Tags: data-recovery, raid, mdadm

I used `mkfs.exfat /dev/md0p1` by mistake, and killed my RAID 1 instead of formatting a micro SD card. Very dumb, I know. How can I undo this colossal mistake? I'm reasonably confident that the two hard drives that used to make up the RAID are still intact, since all I have done is run pointless `mdadm` and `testdisk` checks since The Incident. It's just that the MD file system has been ruined and/or made inaccessible ever since I told the machine to make it `exfat`.

I'm obviously happy to post the results of any checks that anyone needs to see to help with this, but it is a little tricky since I can only run the damaged machine in "recovery root shell" mode--I just have to retype any output on the tablet I'm using to post this question.

EDIT to add a few details:
Ubuntu 14.04 is installed on a separate hard disk. The RAID was mounted as my `/home` directory.

Comment: Simply restore your `\home` from your latest backup. (You did make a backup, right?) To save having to retype any output on your tablet, boot your system from a live media which will allow you to copy and paste output rather than retyping which could lead to errors and further confusion. Note that RAID 1 is a mirror with both drives containing the same data. Running Testdisk on the individual drives might yield results.

Comment: The RAID was the backup, unfortunately. Until a few days ago, I lacked the imagination to foresee a situation where I would destroy it completely in one fell swoop. I only anticipated needing to use the mirror because of a hardware failure--not a "me failure."

Comment: With ultimate power comes ultimate responsibility.  Have you tried using Testdisk to recover files off one member of the RAID 1 set?

Comment: Right after the incident, I ran the machine off a USB stick in "try without installing" mode, but I think my graphics card or something wasn't playing friendly--text glitches and random crashes. The root shell is stable. If someone requests that I post something too long to retype, I'll go back into that mode and cross my fingers.

Comment: Testdisk on either array member detects an EFI GPT partition. Subsequent analysis of that partition finds it is a "1 P Linux Raid" of a plausible size in sectors, identified with a name that makes sense. Quick search of that partition locates one chunk of "MS data ext4, blocksize=4096, Large file Sparse superblock, 4000 GB/3726 GiB." But using the "p" command to list files reports, "No file found, filesystem may be damaged."  Running deeper search now.

Comment: Related: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/data-recovery-from-one-raid-1-disk-4175508911/

Comment: Deep scan with testdisk ran all day yesterday on one of the array components. It found the crucial data range, plus a lot of tiny garbage data that I presume is leftover from before I put the drive in the RAID. Unfortunately, it does not permit me to view the files in the good data range, or any of the garbage data. I just get "no file found, filesystem may be damaged."

Comment: I found this elsewhere.     https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=101201&p=574974#p574885     Similar in many respects, but I don't know how to apply the solution in my case, since the person with the problem never posted details of the solution. I will read up on fsck after work today and see if it can help me. Meanwhile, any further thoughts from this community would be would be appreciated.

Comment: I also posted some relevant (?) notes about my efforts on this problem here: http://askubuntu.com/q/747869/520556

Comment: What exactly does mkfs.exfat do? What happens if I simply  repeat my mistake and apply mkfs.ext4 to the same /dev I messed up in the first place?

Comment: mkfs creates a file system. Have you tried using google? or `man mkfs`? Writing further data to the volume in question will not help your recovery efforts, so don't.

Comment: I've used man and google. I can't mount the array or it's drives, and haven't attempted to write anything. All I've done is analysis with testdisk, which tells me the fs is broken, there are files it can't list, and partitions I can't access. The wording, "what exactly does mkfs.exfat do" was meant to learn the specific changes mkfs makes--what does it alter? My foolish mkfs.exfat operation on an array with 2 4-Tb drives took about 1 second, so I doubt the command changed much. My hope was that if it just overwrote headers/etc., maybe another mkfs command could undo the damage. Guess not.

Comment: overwriting more of the disk will not be helpful. Backups are helpful. A quick google search of `mkfs.exfat ` produces https://manned.org/mkfs.exfat. Exactly what it does depends on the switches that you used, if none then the defaults are used. Based on the time you state you likely just created a file allocation table (overwriting all data under the table). If the data is critical and `sudo testdisk` can't recover the data I suggest you find a company in your region that specializes in data recovery and pay them to recover it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So I guess it's time to give up hope on handling this myself. It's annoying that if all I did is destroy the FAT, I can't port out the data (even with no names or directory structure) to another drive without paying someone. If I could afford that, I'd probably have been able to afford a backup drive. But that's the breaks. I'll unplug one of the Raid drives and save it for when I have the money to recover the data. It's mostly family photos and FLACs of my CDs . The photos will still be there in a year, and the CDs are still on my shelf.

Comment: IT Systems Admin 101: Do Not Rely on RAID as a Sole Backup Solution.  I hate to make this statement but it is 100% accurate...

Comment: Yeah yeah. I get it. I've big idiot. Back up the backup. I'll definitely do that in the future. And I now  realize there's no value to a Raid for a person like me (i.e. not running a server/business). Someone like me is way more likely to do something stupid to lose files than suffer a drive failure. I would have been better off using sda as the data drive and sdb for backup. Lesson learned. It's disappointing that "data recovery" is apparently a magical technology that the rest of us can't access and do ourselves. But I also get why those who can do recovery wouldn't share their secrets.

Comment: Re "Do not rely on RAID as a sole backup solution" - it's better not treat it as a backup *at all*, because that's not what it does. It's designed to reduce downtime of an always-on system in the event of a hardware failure of a single drive. It doesn't help in case of accidental deletion, data corruption, virus attack, unauthorised access, hardware failure in things other than a single drive (eg drive controller, motherboard, power supply), etc which are other reasons for needing backup.

Comment: Yep. Got it. A home user with only data of sentimental value, rather than critical server/monetary data is wasting effort on a Raid. I will never be this dumb again. I'll use any redundant disks I can afford for actual backup. And even though all have done is ruin my file allocation table, the only suggestions to recover my data are getbackdatantfs or paying someone else to recover the data. Reassembling the raid is not an option, and testdisk is the only software that can help--if it doesn't work, there's nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1):

Break the mirror by placing one of the two drives on the shelf and do not do anything to it. (At least you'll be no worse off than you are now)

Try to access the other drive directly with `sudo testdisk` to see if you can find the ext partition that you mangled and/or files that remain on the disk.
If this fails and the data is critical to you, you can use a professional data recovery service such as [Ontrack](https://www.krollontrack.com/ps211-alt-data-recovery/?gclid=CNSltomC2MsCFQMQaQodJZ0DZA) to recover most of the data from the unmodified (since the incident) disk on the shelf.

EDIT: Based on your recent comment regarding family photos you might try `photorec` which is part of the testdisk package. Since the photorec approach is based on the underlying data and ignores the filesystem you may get decent results. You will need a drive with sufficient space to recover the files to.

More information is available [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and a step by step tutorial can be found on [this page](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) as `man photorec` might seem a bit cryptic.

Comment: Knowing the disk was just modified, the method to use a file recovery system should yield decent results.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1º Unplug the hard drive you accidentaly formatted and plug it in another computer
2º Install in that computer the RAID controllers
3º Use an app like GetBackDataNTFS (windows) to recover your hdd

Comment: If you read the comments you'll discover that the original filesystem was ext4 and no Windows software will recognize that.